# Installed new battery not start

Tags: battery, ignition

My Honda CR-V never have been any wrong or issues before. One week of extremely cold weather my battery died and I changed it with new one but no start, no light, no click at all. What shall I do please any body can give suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would check all the terminals and connections - it is possible you disturbed something when you replaced the battery.

The battery terminals need to be clean and tight

Comment: Would you please put your answer (this answer) onto the other question? Same OP, yet this one is "unregistered". I'm closing this question, as most likely the OP cannot do anything with this one. We'll leave the other one open.